# Wiper linkage converting from RHD to LHD

Tags: bmw, windshield-wipers, conversion

What is main diferences beetwen RHD and LHD wiper linkage?
Is possible some how convert RHD -> LHD wiper linkage for BMW E46?

I have good working LHD wiper linkage motor and full RHD linkage with motor.

[image: BMW E46 wiper linkage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will almost certainly be a mirror image of each other. Looking at your diagram, it appears the left hand arm (i.e. that going to parts 5 and 6) is longer than the other, and has a slight curve to it.

You might find you can use some of the parts from the LHD one to repair the motor of the RHD one, but probably not as they are usually sealed units these days.

Comment: I think you are totaly right. And how you think USA and Europe versions is equal?

Comment: I would expect there to just be two versions, one for LHD and one for RHD